# We have $\pi(R) = \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(V)$ is simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory, semi-simple-rings

> Let $R$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and $(\pi, V )$ a finite dimensional simple $R$-module. Show that

(a) The ring $\pi(R) \subset \operatorname{End}_{\mathbb{C}}(V)$ is simple.

(b) We have $\pi(R) = \operatorname{End}_\mathbb{C}(V)$.

So I want to show that $\pi(R)$ is Artinian, and then show that its Jacobson radical is $0$, so then I can conclude it is semisimple. I'm not sure how to show it is Artinian, and where do I go after I show it is semisimple. Maybe work with the finite dimensionality of the endomorphism ring?

Comment: I'm not sure about the validity of your strategy, but the fact that $\pi(R)$ is artinian follows from the fact that its ideals are complex vector subspaces of the finite dimensional complex vector space $\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{C}(V)$ (and so the descending chain condition is immediate).

Comment: It seems that Nakayama's lemma would also imply that $J.V\neq V$, where $J=J(\pi(R))$, is a proper submodule of $V$, and hence has to be zero by simplicity. This implies, since $J\subset\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{C}(V)$, that $J=0$.

Comment: It then follows, setting $\pi(R)=S$, that $S\simeq\prod_{i=1}^r M_{n_i}(\Bbb{C})$: there can only be one factor since otherwise the nonzero, non-identity  projection corresponding to $(I_{n_1},0,\dots,0)$ would define nontrivial invariant subspaces of $V$. Thus $S\simeq M_{m}(\Bbb{C})$ for some $m\leq n=\mathrm{dim}(V)$.Thus $S$ is simple. We conclude by recalling that $M_m(\Bbb{C})$ has up to isomorphims a single simple module which has dimension $m$. Thus $V$ has dimension $m$ and so $m=\mathrm{dim}(V)$ and  $S=\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{C}(V)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us put $S=\pi(R)$ and $J$ its Jacobson radical. Note that $V$ is a simple $S$-module.

**$S$ is semi-simple.** Indeed, $S$ is artinian since its left ideals are complex subspaces of $S\subset\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{C}(V)$, which has finite dimension, and thus satisfy the descending chain condition. $S$ is also Jacobson semi-simple since by Nakayama's lemma and finite generation of $V$, $JV$ is a proper $S$-submodule of $V$ and therefore zero by simplicity of $V$ (*). It follows that $J=0$ and thus that $S$ is semi-simple.

(*) Alternatively, and more to the point, $JV=0$ by simplicity of $V$ as an $S$-module and by definition of the Jacobson radical as those elements in $S$ killing all simple $S$-modules.

**$S$ is simple.** By the Artin-Wedderburn theorem and the fact that there are no nontrivial finite dimensional complex division algebras we have $S\simeq\prod_{i=1}^rM_{n_i}(\Bbb{C})$. In fact, $r=1$ and $S\simeq M_m(\Bbb{C})$. Indeed, if there were two factors or more, the element $e$ of $S$ corresponding to $(I_{n_1},0,\dots,0)$ would define a nontrivial central idempotent of $S$, and thus two nontrivial $S$-submodules $\mathrm{Ker}(e)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(e)$, contradicting the simplicity of $V$ as an $S$-module.

**$S=\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{C}(V)$.** Recall that $M_m(\Bbb{C})$ has up to isomorphism a single simple module which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}^m$. We conclude that $V$ has dimension $\mathrm{dim}(V)=m$ and $S$ dimension $\mathrm{dim}(V)^2$. Therefore $S=\mathrm{End}_\Bbb{C}(V)$.

Comment: How do we know that $V$ is a simple $S$-module?

Comment: The $S$-submodules of $V$ are precisely the $R$-submodules of $V$ and since $V$ is a simple $R$-module it is a simple $S$-module.